# JButton changes text colour of textfield

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I am trying to change the text colour in JTextfield using the
JButton but somehow i 
am not able to find the specific function to do so. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
Also it would be a real help if i could get the source from where i could search
different functions with their use, used in java.

Comment: Seriously, do **some** research before coming here, and if you have found something, include the fruits of your research with your question. That will improve your question greatly, and thereby improve your answers.

Comment: Do a Google search for "Java 8 javadocs" this will give you the jse API documentation

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to change the text colour in JTextfield using the JButton but somehow i am not able to find the specific function to do so.

That's because there is no one "function" that changes text color from a JButton. You have to create code to do it. Consider using:

- ActionListener to respond to button press
- `setForeground(Color newColor)` call on the JTextField to set its foreground/text color.
- The specifics on how to make these calls will all depend on your current code, something that we have not seen yet.
- Check the Swing tutorials and do a little more research in the future and show your attempt when asking similar questions. Else we'll have no idea what you may be doing wrong. Please look at the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) as well as [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how you can improve this question and increase your odds of getting decent answers.

Comment: Answered as a community wiki due to the low-quality of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Quick example of what you could do

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Button");

    public void changeColor(Color background, Color foreground){ 
        btn.setBackground(background);
        btn.setForeground(foreground);

    }
```

[image]