# Change JLabel colour repeatedly each time when JButton pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I'm trying to make a traffic light program, changing the foreground colour of JLabel from red to yellow to green, everytime I press JButton (i.e once i press JButton, JLabel turns red, then when i again press JButton it turns yellow and so on). But somehow the colour changes only once to red & nothing happens on further pressing JButton. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class traffic {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    traffic window = new traffic();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public traffic() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 798, 512);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblTrafficLight = new JLabel("Traffic Light");
        lblTrafficLight.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 40));
        lblTrafficLight.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblTrafficLight.setBounds(190, 11, 403, 61);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblTrafficLight);

        JLabel lblRed = new JLabel("RED");
        lblRed.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblRed.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        lblRed.setBounds(273, 125, 249, 61);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblRed);

        JButton btnButton = new JButton("Button");
        btnButton.setActionCommand("B");
        btnButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                if(btnButton.getActionCommand().equals("B"))
                {
                lblRed.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
                if(btnButton.getActionCommand().equals("B"))
                {
                    lblRed.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
                }
                if(btnButton.getActionCommand().equals("B"))
                {
                    lblRed.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                }
                if(btnButton.getActionCommand().equals("B"))
                {
                    lblRed.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
                }
                if(btnButton.getActionCommand().equals("B"))
                {
                    lblRed.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        });
        btnButton.setBounds(353, 346, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a null layout!!! Swing was designed to be used with [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Read this tutorial and then look at the table of contents for other Swing basics so you don't need to ask so many questions.

Comment: At least this time he is showing code, a major improvement from his [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028972/jbutton-changes-text-colour-of-textfield).

Comment: How about you use a counter, so each time the button is clicked, you update the counter and based on its value you set the colour of the label?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same actionCommand, `B` for each if block, and so all of the blocks will always run, and the last block will be the one seen.

e.g.,

```
int x = 1;
if (x == 1) {
    // do something
}
if (x == 1) {
    // do something else
}
```

all blocks will be done!

Either change the actionCommands used, or don't use actionCommand String but rather an incrementing int index. Also, don't use MouseListeners for JButtons but rather ActionListeners.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Traffic2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = 300;
    private static final String[] STRINGS = {"Red", "Blue", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Cyan"};
    private Map<String, Color> stringColorMap = new HashMap<>();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private int index = 0;

    public Traffic2() {
        stringColorMap.put("Red", Color.red);
        stringColorMap.put("Blue", Color.blue);
        stringColorMap.put("Orange", Color.orange);
        stringColorMap.put("Yellow", Color.YELLOW);
        stringColorMap.put("Green", Color.GREEN);
        stringColorMap.put("Cyan", Color.CYAN);  

        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 40f));
        String key = STRINGS[index];
        label.setText(key);
        label.setForeground(stringColorMap.get(key));
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        centerPanel.add(label);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Change Color") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                index++;
                index %= STRINGS.length;

                String key = STRINGS[index];
                label.setText(key);
                label.setForeground(stringColorMap.get(key));
            }
        }));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Traffic2 mainPanel = new Traffic2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Traffic2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I copied the program and it runs perfectly but i'm very new to programing in java and half of the things in your program seems complication to me and is going above my head.